# Spring Project is not building in the eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, build

I'm using `Eclipse 4.17 for Mac OS X`

Java version in the build path: `Java SE 15`

And I'm facing the issue while building the spring project.

It is throwing an error:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'Project'.
Could not initialize class org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.jar.JarArchiver
```

** It was working fine with older versions of the eclipse but the newer version of the eclipse is not supporting the Java v1.8

Let me know if any further information is required.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Eclipse 4.17 is too old for Big Sur. **Eclipse 2020-12 (4.18) supports Java 8 and even older Java versions**. You are confusing this with the Java 11 or higher needed to run Eclipse. Eclipse is shipped with an embedded Java 15 used to run Eclipse and which you can use to run your application, but don't have to.

Comment: Installed version 4.18 but still, it is asking for a version 11 or above.

Comment: Weird how this looks so similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65816900/eclipse-compatibility-issue-with-m1-chip . It's not M1. It's not Eclipse. Pretty sure it's the version of Maven and newer versions of Java.

Comment: Are you talking about the Eclipse Installer or did you install an IDE package as `.dmg` file or did you update an existing installation? In all cases, I recommend to use the embedded JustJ Java 15 to run Eclipse. But of course, you can also use a Java 11 or higher that is installed on your system to run Eclipse (not recommended in your case).

Comment: @nitind Yes, it was the version compatibility issue of maven and Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The older version of maven does not include the `org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.jar` for building the project.

Updated the version of maven to `3.6.3` it downloaded the jar on the local repository and while building the project the jar was found by maven in the path.

---

Also, it worked with older versions of Java too. So, I'm back to Java v1.8
So the issue was nothing to do with the java version.